# What was Dr Smith's motivation for being on the colony ship?

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-2018

It's impossible to ask this question without spoilers.

In Episode 3 we learn via a flashback [that](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/LostInSpace2018);

> The opening is a flashback to Dr. Smith's past, revealing her real name: June Harris. Her sister, an accomplished businesswoman, offered to leave all her possessions to June as she left for Alpha Centauri. June, a petty criminal and family Black Sheep, drugged her and stole her identity, leaving her behind instead.

Why would she do this? Did I miss something later in the episode or series that explains it? As far as I can see the disreputable sister is being offered the chance to take possession of the "good" sister's life on Earth. Her house, her possessions, even if this doesn't include her bank account (gotta pay for that smuggled whisky somehow), it looks as if June would be set up for life just living off this stash. Why would she throw this away for a life pretending to be someone else, knowing it could all go wrong if she's found out? Why not take the fresh start on Earth?

Comment: Because she could do the same, while surviving on another planet?

Answer (score 5):

A few people mentioned it, the mechanic, Don West said that basically the Earth is all done and the new colony is the only hope for survival.

So if you weren't chosen to go you're doomed to live on Earth for however much time it has left.

June said the hell with that and being a thief and a sociopath she'll just steal her sister's identity and have a new chance at a bright future.

So while her sister's offer was charitable, it was on a dead or dying world. June decided she wanted the real prize and escape her past and a dying Earth.

Comment: It is presumed that the a Earths fate is related to the impact of the "Winter Star".

Comment: It didn't seem quite so bleak in later flashbacks. When the Robinson's discussed trying to get on the colony ships they had positives and negatives. If the Earth was doomed it would have been a very different conversation.

Comment: There was an instance in a flashback where the Robinsons were touring the town. They had to wear breathing masks to go outside. There was even a space for them to put the masks which indicates this is just common practice now. So if the Earth wasn't doomed, it didn't seem like a pleasant place to be.

Comment: @Deev - That's the way it seemed to me at first, too, but later it seemed to me like all the nastiness was caused by whatever they got the alien technology from (and would go away). That the government had simply taken the opportunity to build ships that could carry humans to settle on other planets.

Comment: Deev is right; there is another scene where someone says "those left on earth won't have much of life." This suggests that people will survive but not well.